# Is there a way to preview DynamicResources that are merged into App.xaml resouces?

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary, dynamicresource

I have an app in WPF and created a service that adds my brushes and colors into a *ResourceDictionary* and then merges this dictionary with *App.xaml* resources. This looks somethings like this (obvously the original code is bigger. This is the main idea):

```cs
private void ConfigureApplicationVisual()
{
    Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(new AbdrakovBundledTheme()
    {
        IsDarkMode = true,
        ExtendedColors = new Dictionary<string, ColorPair>()
        {
            { "TextForeground", new ColorPair(Colors.AliceBlue, Colors.Black) },
            // similar things...
        }
    }.SetTheme());
}
```

(Then inside *SetTheme* method colors are adding into *AbdrakovBundledTheme* (that is inheritted from *ResourceDictionary*) like `sourceDictionary[name + "Color"] = value;` and returns the *AbdrakovBundledTheme* as dictionary to be merged further)

So what do I want? I want the colors to appear in design mode (as *StaticResource*s do). I know that WPF compiles and runs some blocks of code at runtime to show them in designer. Is it possible to do this with *DynamicResources*?
Two more things:

1. I already saw similar question on SO [Preview of dynamicresources in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20922082/preview-of-dynamicresources-in-wpf) but I can't do as they did. My *AbdrakovBundledTheme* is also kinda dynamic.
2. I tried to call the method in *App* constructor and in *OnStartup* but there was no result.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11669848/how-to-load-a-wpf-resource-dictionary-at-design-time